# Jest error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I am getting this error while testing this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { translate } from 'react-i18next';
import TableItemsHeaders from './TableItemsHeaders';

const TableItemsHeader = ({ t }) => {
  const tableItemsHeaders = TableItemsHeaders(t);

  return (
    <div className="row header">
      {tableItemsHeaders.map(itemsHeaders => (
        <div className="cell" key={itemsHeaders.key}>
          {itemsHeaders.header}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

TableItemsHeader.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default translate()(TableItemsHeader);
```

And all I have in the test is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import TableItemsHeader from '../../TableItemsHeader';

describe('The Shipments/TableItemsHeaders component', () => {
  let props;

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      t: k => k,
    };
  });

  it('renders TableItemsHeader)', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TableItemsHeader {...props} />);

    expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);

    console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });
});
```

And here is the error:

```
 FAIL  src/client/pages/Shipments/__tests__/components/TableItemsHeader-test.js
  The Shipments/TableItemsHeaders component
    ✕ renders TableItemsHeader) (12ms)

  ● The Shipments/TableItemsHeaders component › renders TableItemsHeader)

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

      13 | 
      14 |   it('renders TableItemsHeader)', () => {
    > 15 |     const wrapper = shallow(<TableItemsHeader {...props} />);
         |                     ^
      16 | 
      17 |     const componentInstance = wrapper.instance();
      18 | 

at new Translate (node_modules/react-i18next/dist/commonjs/translate.js:63:135)
```

Comment: Does `translate()` need to take options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has to do with `react-i18next` not being configured correctly in your testing environment. `translate()` wraps your component and is outside its provider context in your testing environment. To mock the library you can look here: https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing. However, I find it annoying to mock and since you're not testing its functionality I usually just look at the wrapped 
component like this:

`const wrapper = shallow(<TableItemsHeader.WrappedComponent {...props} />);`